# Java cucumber a table of dates

Tags: java, date, cucumber

I guess this should be easy enough but I don't see it in the documentation.

How does one map a table of dates in the form mm/dd/yyyy into a List of java.util.Date.

My cucumber code is as below:

```
And I have holidays
  | Date       |
  | 12/25/2014 |
  | 11/27/2014 |
  | 09/01/2014 |
  | 07/04/2014 |
  | 05/26/2014 |
  | 04/18/2014 |
  | 02/17/2014 |
  | 01/20/2014 |
  | 01/01/2014 |
  | 12/25/2013 |
  | 11/28/2013 |
  | 09/02/2013 |
  | 07/04/2013 |
  | 05/27/2013 |
  | 03/29/2013 |
```

Get the error:

> cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Couldn't convert "Date" to an instance of: [class java.util.Date]

This does the trick but is there anything easier:

```
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    List<List<String>> cells = dt.cells(0);
    Set<Date> holidays = new HashSet();
    int count = 0;
    for(List<String> row : cells){
        count++;
        //Avoid the header
        if(count == 1)continue;
        try {
            holidays.add(sdf.parse(row.get(0)));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't have any XP with Cucumber (we're playing with JBehave), but for the first search I found [this doc](http://cukes.info/step-definitions.html). Take a look on _String Transformations_ and _Date Tables_. Probably that will help you.

Comment: I've seen that doc.  It tells you how to transform a date when in a standalone field but not what it is in a table.

Answer (score 2):

A # language: header on the first line of a feature file tells Cucumber what spoken language to use, by default it's en. If you want use date format in Chinese language like this 2016-04-02, you should do this:

# language: zh-CN

Feature: MyFeatureName

Answer (score 0):

You can change your default JVM Locale to let cucumber use the default date converter.

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use @Format("MM/dd/yyyy") and from data table you can extract it as a list of Date or can use the raw data as well to access it. Cheers mate

```
    @And("^I have holidays:$")
    public void theFollowingGroupInDatabase(@Format("MM/dd/yyyy") DataTable dataTable) throws Throwable {
             List<Date> dates = dataTable.asList(Date.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem converting a DataTable containing dates as well as other numeric and text values into an Entity.

The soloution was to use Cucumber 3.0.0 or later which allows you to implement a custom mapping for any object.

The cucumber DataTable documentation shows you how to do this:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/datatable

And this is an example from their code which does it:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-calculator-testng/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/calculator/ParameterTypes.java

Easiest way to implement it would be to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51441216/5052928):

Answer (score -1):

Modern cucumber-jvm supports format annotation, see https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/Format.java