# Register LocalDateTime xstream transformer with cucumber datatable

Tags: java, cucumber, xstream, gherkin

I have the following datatable in a Gherkin file:

```
Given the system knows about the following equipments:
| SerialNumber | CreationDate             |
| 1234A        | 2016-05-17T08:41:17.970Z |
| 5678A        | 2012-03-16T08:21:17.970Z |
```

And the following matching step definition in java :

```
@Given("^the system knows about the following equipments:$")
public void theSystemKnowsAboutTheFollowingEquipments(List<Equipment> equipments) throws Throwable {
        // step code...
}
```

With the POJO Equipment.java :

```
public class Equipment {
    private String equipmentId;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

}
```

Since cucumber does not support LocalDateTime transformation by default, I would like to register my custom xstream Transformer in order for LocalDateTime to be handled correctly inside my Equipment POJO. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have access to the code of the Equipment POJO.
You can use the `@XStreamConverter` annotation to register your `XStream` converter class.

1. The column names in the datatable and fields in the desired POJO need to match so that Cucumber can do its magic of matching columns to respective fields.
2. Create a custom `DTZConverter` class extending `AbstractSingleValueConverter` for the DateTime parsing logic. Do modify the pattern used below.

> ```
> public class DTZConverter extends AbstractSingleValueConverter {
>
>       @Override
>       public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
>           return type.equals(LocalDateTime.class);
>       }
>
>       @Override
>       public Object fromString(String dtz) {
>           DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
>           return LocalDateTime.parse(dtz, formatter);
>       }
>     }
> ```

3. Annotate the creationDate field with `@XStreamConverter(DTZConverter.class)`.

> ```
> public class Equipment {
>
>   private String equipmentId;
>
>   @XStreamConverter(DTZConverter.class)
>     private LocalDateTime creationDate;
>
>
>   @Override
>   public String toString() {      
>       return "Equipment [equipmentId=" + equipmentId + ", creationDate="
>               + creationDate + "]";
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Ok thanks this option works well but the problem with it is that it requires to add dependencies to cucumber/xstream in the runtime code (@XStreamConverter annotation in the POJO and the custom converter) while it is only required inside the tests

Comment: So the ideal solution for you would be xstream picking up the mapping of the localdatetime class and the converter from a properties file. I am not aware of a this possibility, then again I could be wrong.

Comment: One solution could be that you edit the LocalizedXStream which is an inner class of LocalizedXStreams. Create a similar package structure cucumber.runtime.xstream in your code, copy and paste the existing class inside it. In the inner class constructor add the line - register(converterRegistry, new DTZConverter());. Now you will not need any annotations in POJO for conversion.

Comment: Other could be extending the Equipment POJO in your test code with EqTestPOJO. In the EqTestPOJO add the creation date field and the XStreamConverter annotation to it. Modify the stepdef to take a list of this new class. In the EqTestPOJO add a static method to return a list of the original EqPOJO with the updated creationDate using a loop. Call this method from the stepdef to get the list of original list of Equipment POJO.This will remove the need for XStreamConverter annotation in original POJO.

Answer (score 0):

How about registering your object in the type registry and letting jackson convert it for you:

Create a class implementing `cucumber.api.TypeRegistryConfigurer`

Implement method `configureTypeRegistry` as below:

```
private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
.....
.....
@Override
public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
    typeRegistry.defineDataTableType(new DataTableType(
            Equipment.class,
            (Map<String, String> row) -> objectMapper.convertValue(row, classType))
    );
}
```

And that's it!

Comment: This feature is available since the cucumber version 3.0.0 : https://cucumber.io/blog/2018/05/19/announcing-cucumber-jvm-3-0-0